# Selenium findElement(By.cssSelector) for "text" that has no associated tag

Tags: css, selenium, text, selector, findelement

Looking at HTML code with this as a web page drop list option:

```
<div class="select5-result-label" id="select5-result-label-31" role="option">
    <span class="select2-match"></span>
    "Jedi"
</div>
```

Attempting to use selenium css selectors to select/click the "Jedi" option.  Tried:

```
- driver.findElement(By.id("select5-result-label-31")).click();  
- driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div#select5-result-label-31")).click();
- driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[text='Jedi']")).click();
```

but none of the attempts above have been able to select the drop list value. Returns runtime error message of:

```
*** Element info: {Using=css selector, value=div[text='Jedi']}
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
```

Suspect it is because the "Jedi" value has no tag.  Any suggestions to select/click the option above? Very much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: The Exception associated to `div[text='Jedi']` because its a invalid selector. You can try it using xpath `//div[contains(.,'Jedi')]` and post the error if it wont work. also the error you faced while tried your first 2 locator.

Comment: can you give us the URL that you are testing on?

Comment: @NarendraR Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element <div id="content-container" class="disable-click">...</div> is not clickable at point (552, 416). Other element would receive the click: <div id="select2-drop-mask" class="select2-drop-mask" style=""></div>

Comment: @NarendraR   The suggested html line is:  <div class="select2-result-label" id="select2-result-label-69" role="option">. The "..69" is a different number each time formi is opened. This could be difficult scripting as number changes every time.